# Complex analysis inequalities

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $z$ is real, then
$$\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2 + 1}\right| \leq \frac{1}{|z|^2 + 1}.$$

I don't see how this is true.
The left hand side simplifies as: $\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2 + 1}\right| = \frac{1}{|z^2 + 1|} \geq \frac{1}{|z|^2 + 1}$ by triangle inequality. Am I missing something?
Edit: It seems that for any real $z$, both sides equal to each other.......??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z$ is real, then $|e^{iz}|=1$ and $|z^2+1|=z^2+1=|z|^2+1$, hence

$\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2 + 1}\right|=\frac{1}{z^2+1}=\frac{1}{|z|^2+1}$.

Comment: Thank you. I think they put that in there on purpose, actually.  
What would happen if $z$ was not necessarily real?

Comment: We have $\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2 + 1}\right| \to \infty$ for $z \to i$. Observe that $\frac{1}{|z|^2 + 1} \le 1$,.

Comment: What condition on $z$ will allow the inequality: $\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2 + 1}\right| < \frac{1}{|z|^2 + 1}$ to hold true (with $z$ being not necessarily real)?